# c# XML reaching node

Tags: c#, xml

I need query depending on this condition..If "Title" contain word "Love" then I need to get related Movie Name

```
<mmReply command="getSongsByQuery" userData="hello" status="ok">
<contents>
<songList recordCount="3">
  <song songId="83">
    <field id="12" name="Run Time">03:42</field>
    <field id="102" name="Artist">Ten Years After</field>
    <field id="103" name="Title">I'd Love To Change The World</field>
    <field id="104" name="Movie">Movie Name</field>
  </song>
  <song songId="81">
    <field id="12" name="Run Time">03:08</field>
    <field id="102" name="Artist">Stephen Stills</field>
    <field id="103" name="Title">Love The One You're With</field>
    <field id="104" name="Movie">Movie Name</field>
  </song>
  <song songId="54">
    <field id="12" name="Run Time">05:30</field>
    <field id="102" name="Artist">Led Zeppelin</field>
    <field id="103" name="Title">Whole Lotta</field>
    <field id="104" name="Movie">Movie Name</field>
  </song>
</songList>
```

Below I don't know how to get Movie

```
(from c in data.Descendants("song")
               from fld in c.Elements("field")
               where fld.Value.ToLower().Contains("love") && getSeconds(c.Element("field").Value) > 120 //120 is song length
               select new SongInfo()
               {
                   songId = Convert.ToInt32(c.Attribute("songId").Value),
                   song = fld.Value, // keyword.song,
                   Movie = ?????
                   songDuration = getSeconds(c.Element("field").Value),
                   counts = keyword.counts,
                   tweetDateTime = keyword.tweetDateTime
               }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=564

Comment: So have you tried anything to solve your problem?

Comment: What is not working? Where is your code? Do you get an exception?

Comment: I Edit above.. added code that i tried don't know how to get movie from XML  @AndyKorneyev

Comment: From the node with the title you need to go to the parent, then its child with the attribute of movie to get the inner text. Or just look at the siblings of the node with the title to find the correct item.  Have you thought about what was necessary from an algorithm perspective?  Have you tried either option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this can be easily done with LINQ to XML (since you're already using it in your code) like this:

```
var songs = data.XPathSelectElements("/mmReply/contents/songList/song/field[@name='Title']")
    .Where(x => x.Value.Contains("Love"))
    .Select(x => new {
                        songID = x.Parent.Attribute("songId").Value, 
                        movieName = x.Parent.XPathSelectElement("field[@name='Movie']").Value
                     }
            );
```

In this sample `data` is instance of [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in which your xml content was loaded (note your sample xml is not well-formed because it misses `</contents>` and `</mmReply>` closing tags).

Note here I'm creating IEnumerable of anonymous type just for simplicity, and you should create your `SongInfo` instance instead.

Comment: Are you sure you're testing it on the xml data having the same structure as from your sample? Because from your sample xml (with added missed close tags, as I've mentioned) this code outputs two elements songId 83 and 81 and their movie names at my computer.

Comment: I'm having closing tags and same XML still not getting.. :( Null va

Comment: Well, the only reason I can suppose - is that your `data` is `XElement` not `XDocument`. In that case XPath for the first `XPathSelectElements` expression should be `"contents/songList/song/field[@name='Title']"` because in this case element `mmReply` is `data` itself.

Comment: I'm using above code as "data.XPathSelectElements("contents/songList/song/field[@name='Title']")" for testing purpose and I'm getting this in songs "{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<System.Xml.Linq.XElement,<>f__AnonymousType1<string,string>>}"

Comment: As I've mentioned in the answer - you don't need anonymous type, I've write it just for illustration (as I don't have your `SongInfo` class here and cant compile with it). You need to create new `SongInfo` and populate its fields in `.Select`

Comment: This once work with slight modification.... var songs = (from fld in data.XPathSelectElements("/mmReply/contents/songList/song/field[@name='Title']")
                    where fld.Value.ToLower().Contains("love")
                    select new
                    {                      
                        movie = fld.Parent.XPathSelectElement("field[@name='Movie']").Value
                    }).FirstOrDefault();